# Using grouby and sum in a query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have quite a big query and I'm trying to grab the sum of the orders.price column. With the below code, it returns just 44.00, which is the price for the first row. When I run the raw SQL, it is returning a column with 1,000+ rows of prices in a column called "AGGREGATE". I want to return a single total for all of these prices.

When I remove the groupBy, it works mostly fine. However, the groupby is there as I seem to get duplicate rows back.

```
$query = Order::leftJoin('customers', 'orders.customer_id', '=', 'customers.customer_id')
    ->leftJoin('addresses', 'orders.order_id', '=', 'addresses.order_id')
    ->where('orders.customer_id', '!=', 0);

$query->whereIn('user_id', [3, 5, 10, 15]);

$query->groupBy('orders.order_id');

$sum = $query->sum('orders.price');
```

I've omitted some of the code here, but the joins are actually necessary.

Here's the generated SQL:

```
SELECT
    sum(`orders`.`price`) AS AGGREGATE
FROM
    `orders`
LEFT JOIN `customers` ON `orders`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`customer_id`
LEFT JOIN `addresses` ON `orders`.`order_id` = `addresses`.`order_id`
WHERE
    `orders`.`customer_id` IS NOT NULL
AND `orders`.`customer_id` != '0'
AND `orders`.`user_id` IN (3, 5, 10, 15)
GROUP BY
    `orders`.`order_id`
ORDER BY
    `orders`.`order_id` DESC
```

Comment: You might have a mistake in your first line right there: `Order::leftJoin('customers', 'customers.customer_id', '=', 'customers.customer_id')` - you are joining `customers.customer_id` with `customers.customer_id`.

Comment: Yep thanks for pointing that out. That mistake is just from where I slightly rewrote it for SO. Edited

Comment: Thought so, but you never know. By the way, have you tried enabling and dumping the query log? I could imagine that it is a syntax issue, e.g. some parentheses not being generated by the query builder properly.

Comment: I've added the generated SQL to my question. Cheers for the help

Comment: Well, you clearly should get rid of the `groupBy` if you want to have only one total result instead of one result per group (which you could only match with `orders.order_id` in the `select` by the way). It also seems to me that both your `left joins` are completely obsolete, because you are neither using these tables in the `where` clauses nor in a `select`. Left joins do not limit the result in your case at all though. -- Maybe it would be a good point to ask, what your desired output is. I guess the total value for all orders of all customers for some specific user(s)?

Comment: @Namoshek As I said in my original question, I've ommitted some of the query as it's not really relevant to the question. I have other where clauses that require these joins.

Comment: As in my original question, I'd like to return a single number, which is the sum of all `orders.price`.

Comment: What I mean is that the query you showed so far is basically doing [this (see fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36dd23/1), which seems absolutely fine to me. But I assume you want something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36dd23/4), which is basically the same query without `group by` and `order by`. A more comprehensive example could be [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce617/3).

Comment: Unfortunately I need those joins, as well as the groupby to stop duplicates. The query is built up based on a dozen or so conditions (it's effectively an advanced search system). So for example, this may be added: `$query->whereIn('addresses.postcode', ['ab123ab']);` Maybe a better question would be, how could do this join (one order can have zero, one, or multiple addresses), without getting duplicates and needing the groupBy?

Comment: You could perform this as part of the join and use an `inner join` instead of a `left join`. Something like this should work: `... FROM orders INNER JOIN addresses ON addresses.order_id = orders.order_id AND addresses.postcode IN ('ab123', 'bc234')`.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to replace the JOINs with subqueries:

```sql
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM customers
  WHERE orders.customer_id=customers.customer_id
    AND ...
)
```

Then you can remove `GROUP BY`.

If you use relationships:

```php
$query->whereHas('customers', function($query) {
    $query->where(...)
})
```